# repeatedly vs. binding

Tags: clojure, thread-safety, lazy-evaluation

```
(def ^:dynamic *d* 1)

(binding [*d* 2]
  (println *d*)
  (repeatedly 1 #(println *d*)))
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

Why? Why does the function inside the `repeatedly` see the value of the dynamic var from outside the `binding`?

By the way, I checked `(.getId (java.lang.Thread/currentThread))` inside and outside the anonymous function: it's the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lazy sequence created by `repeatedly` is returned from the form, and then realized only when printed via the REPL, after the binding has been "unwound," and it is at this point that the anonymous function is being called. To see that this is the case, try these two variations:

```
(binding [*d* 2]
  (println *d*)
  (let [x (repeatedly 1 #(println *d*))]
    (println (realized? x))
    x))
```

and

```
(binding [*d* 2]
  (println *d*)
  (doall (repeatedly 1 #(println *d*))))
```

The second variation forces the sequence to be fully realized while still within the scope of the binding.

Note that another way to force the issue is to "capture" the binding by using `bound-fn`:

```
(binding [*d* 2]
  (println *d*)
  (repeatedly 1 (bound-fn [] (println *d*))))
```

Comment: That was it. Ouch! This is an easy bug to make. Thanks for the clear explanation—and thanks for pointing me to `bound-fn` and `doall`.